# Get posted value from IoT in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm getting a `POST`-ed data with my php like this

```php
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($data, true);
// etc...
```

I tried the same thing with `Django` like this

```py
@csrf_exempt # because not csrf 
def some_view(request):
    data = request.POST.get()
    print(data)
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')
```

but I was receiving

```
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'key'
```

so I added `""` to the `get()` like this `request.POST.get("")`. But I'm getting `None` now.
How could I receive posted data without `form`???

*UPDATE:*

I was able recieve the data. It was in `request.body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data is parsed as a JSON, you can use `request.body` to get the data.

Syntax:

```
import json
data = request.body.decode('utf-8')
json.decode(data)
```

Comment: I have no `html` file and IoT sending just a `string` so the first one is not possible and with `dict()` I'm getting `{}` But I'm sure the data are sent, because I can receive it with the `php` above

Comment: Try `request.POST.items()` and check whether you get any values

Comment: thanks! I got `<generator object MultiValueDict.items at 0x7fc83d104cf0>` should I use `next()` now?

Comment: It should normally return a list :( . Please try this as well: `request.POST.keys()`

Comment: got `dict_keys([])` I think something is not good in data receiving ... But  without `urls.py` the above code is all I have there ..

Comment: This means nothing was received to the `POST` end. Can you add the IOT Device code to your question. The part responsible for posting the data is enough

Comment: its based on android tablet, with app inside which sending the data (I edited the questions), the only setting there are the setting I wrote in question section

Comment: How is your `urls.py` file looks like?

Comment: `from . import views
`, `path("kaoiro-post/", views.my_view, name="kaoiro-post"),`

Comment: Try `print(request.body)`

Comment: I got it! Body looks like: `b'{"mac":"8CFCA00442D7","userId":"08914"`

Comment: Cool! You can do something like this: `import json` `data = request.body.decode('utf-8')` `json.decode(data)`

Comment: Please consider approving the answer if it helped :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)